# How to Run Queues & Configure Laravel ENV for Amazon SQS

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, laravel-5

I'm having trouble working with Amazons SQS within my Laravel 5.2 app. My app queued events work fine when i use database queue drivers, but not when I use sqs

I think I'm probably not passing Amazons credentials properly. Here my set up from my ENV file

I've installed aws/aws-sdk-php

```
   QUEUE_DRIVER=sqs

   SQS_PUBLIC_KEY=PUBLICKEY
   SQS_SECRET_KEY=SECRETKEY
   SQS_PREFIX=https://sqs.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/NUMBER
   SQS_QUEUE=QUE
```

my config/queue looks like this:

```
'sqs' => [
        'driver' => 'sqs',
        'key'    => env('SQS_PUBLIC_KEY'),
        'secret' => env('SQS_SECRET_KEY'),
        'prefix' => env('SQS_PREFIX'),
        'queue'  => env('SQS_QUEUE'),
        'region' => 'us-east-1',
    ],
```

any guidance would be greatly appreciated

Comment: what does your `config/queue.php` file look like?

Comment: @MikeBarwick Ive updated my question with config figurations

Answer (score 2):

In your `config/queue.php` file, make sure you have the `ENV` values listed.

***Something like this:***

```
'sqs' => [
    'driver' => 'sqs',
    'key'    => env('SQS_PUBLIC_KEY'),
    'secret' => env('SQS_SECRET_KEY'),
    'queue'  => env('SQS_PREFIX'),
    'region' => env('SQS_REGION'),
],
```

Comment: thanks, but I already have it set up like that, still no luck getting AWS SQS to cooperate